# Displaying a Nested List through Recursion

Tags: implementation

I'm having a little bit of problem figuring out an implementation for a function.

Basically, I have a nested list, and I need to display them like so:

```
Root 
  -RItem1
      --Item1
      --RRItem2
         --Item1
         --Item2
  -RItem2
      --RRItem1
          -Item1
          -Item2
      --Item2
```

Note that I will be getting the data in runtime. An item might have an item, that has an item that has an item, etc.

So basically, how would one program this? I know that a recursive function is the way to go, but I'm having trouble with it. Specifically, I have trouble of taking to account the coordinates of my items.

This is an implementation question, so the language is not important.

Comment: Could you give an example of how these lists are nested i.e

`["RItem1",["Item1,["RRItem2",["Item1"],["Item2"]]]]`

Comment: @HennyH Unfortunately, the data is arranged in a quite complex way using linked lists.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function is a good way. You have to pass the 'level' as an argument. Something like that (pseudo Java/Javascript) :

```
function display(item, level) {
   printlnAtLevel(level,item.name)
   if item.hasChildren() {
      foreach(child : item.children) {
          display(child,level+1)
      }
   }
}
display(root,0)
```

Comment: I decided not to accept this answer yet because I felt that the y-coordinate would be a problem. After a lot of thinking I realized that it is a problem and I still couldn't do it. How could I decide the y? I can save the y outside of the function as a global, but how would I do it 'recursively'. Oh, and Thank you very much :3

Comment: In the above code, if I have 1.{a,b} 2. "2" would base its level by "1", not b. If my explanation is hard to understand, please reply and I will try to elaborate above. Thanks!

Comment: @Secret see my other answer

Answer (score 1):

I post another answer with (x,y) :

```
 function display(item, x, y) {
  print(x,y,item.name)
  if item.hasChildren() {
    yTemp = y + 1 
    foreach(child : item.children) {
      display(child,x+1,yTemp++)
   }
  }
 }
 display(root,0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```python
def nodePrint(val,depth):
  print(" "*depth + "-"*depth,val)

def recPrint(l,depth=0):
    #node has no children A) it contains 1 or 0 elements B) if not A then'child' is string
    if len(l) <= 1 or isinstance(l[1],str):
      for value in l:
        nodePrint(value,depth)
    else:
      #node had both head and child in form [ head, [ child1, ... ] ]
      head, children = l[0],l[1:]
      nodePrint(head,depth)
      for child in children:
        recPrint(child,depth+1)
```

Using the following:

```python
t = ["Root",
     [
      "Ritem1",
            [
              "Item1",
               [
               ]
            ],
            [
              "RRItem2",
              [
                "Item1",
                "Item2"
              ]
            ]
     ],
     ["Ritem1",
       [
         "RRItem1",
         [
          "Item1",
          "Item2"
          ]
       ],
       ["Item2"]
     ]
    ]

recPrint(t,depth=0)
```

Produces (The same as you requested)

```python
>>> 
 Root
 - Ritem1
  -- Item1
  -- RRItem2
   --- Item1
   --- Item2
 - Ritem1
  -- RRItem1
   --- Item1
   --- Item2
  -- Item2
```